# EF Core triangular relationship with optional member configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have some trouble configuring a triangular relationship containing an optional member.

I have the following relation:

- A `product` has zero or one `service agreement`, with the primary key of `service agreement` being the primary key of `product`
- A `product` has zero or many `tasks`

Since the primary key of `product` and `service agreement` are identical, I would like to be able to navigate to `tasks` from both `service agreement` and `product`.

I drew [a quick diagram of the desired configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vdpb.png)

The problem is, when adding a `task` to a `product` without a `service agreement`, it generates the following error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pant_test`.`Tasks`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Tasks_ServiceAgreements_ProductId` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`) REFERENCES `ServiceAgreements` (`ServiceId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT)

It obviously expects to reference a `service agreement`, but this is not what is desired. Common advice I found when googling the topic is to set the field on `task` to be nullable, but that is not really an option, as tasks are required to reference a `product`, but not necessarily a `service agreement` (in cases where it does not exist).

`Product - Task` configuration

```
   builder
       .HasOne(task => task.Product)
       .WithMany(p => p.Tasks)
       .HasForeignKey(task => task.ProductId)
       .IsRequired();
```

`Service Agreement - Task` configuration

```
   builder
       .HasOne(task => task.Service)
       .WithMany(service => service.Tasks)
       .HasForeignKey(task => task.ProductId)
       .IsRequired(false);
```

`Product - Service Agreement` configuration

```
    builder
        .HasOne(p => p.Service)
        .WithOne(sa => sa!.Product)
        .HasForeignKey<ServiceAgreement>(sa => sa.ServiceId)
        .IsRequired(false)
```

Is it possible to configure this correctly in EF Core, so it does not generate the error or do i need to remove the `Service Agreement` - `Tasks` navigation property?

I am using EF Core 6, if that makes a difference

Comment: From my point of view there is a design issue.
How can a product have several service agreement if the service agreement has a primary key that is the product key. 
If both share primary keys, a service agreement may be another kind of product. You may use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). Or a service agreement is just a field of a product.

Comment: A product has zero or one service agreement, not multiple